# Map Laravel multiple collection

Tags: laravel

I have three tables (Departments, Provinces, and Districts), they have many-to-many relationships with each other, and their relationship through the "DPD" table.
when I want to access a single department with its all districts and provinces (I mean that this department is located in which districts of which provinces).
here is the relationship between them

```
public function districts(){
    return $this->hasManyThrough(District::class,DPD::class,'district_id','id','id','department_id');
}

public function provinces(){
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Province::class,DPD::class,'province_id','id','id','department_id');
}
```

when I do this

```
Department:: with('provinces','districts')->get()
```

it returns multidimentional collection of department with multiple of provinces and districts.
like

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#4595
 all: [
   App\Models\Department{#4605
     id: 1,
     name: "ریاست مخابره",
     created_at: null,
     updated_at: null,
     provinces: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#4623
       all: [
         App\Models\Province {#4580
           id: 1,
           name: "کابل",
           created_at: null,
           updated_at: null,
           laravel_through_key: 1,
         },
         App\Models\Province {#4630
           id: 1,
           name: "کابل",
           created_at: null,
           updated_at: null,
           laravel_through_key: 1,
         },
       ],
     },
   },
   App\Models\Department{#4613
     id: 2,
     name: "ریاست لوجیستیک",
     created_at: null,
     updated_at: null,
     provinces: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#4566
       all: [
         App\Models\Province {#4617
           id: 2,
           name: "ننګرهار",
           created_at: null,
           updated_at: null,
           laravel_through_key: 2,
         },
         App\Models\Province {#4596
           id: 1,
           name: "کابل",
           created_at: null,
           updated_at: null,
           laravel_through_key: 2,
         },
         App\Models\Province {#4629
           id: 2,
           name: "ننګرهار",
           created_at: null,
           updated_at: null,
           laravel_through_key: 2,
         },
       ],
     },
   },
 ],
```

}
now I want to access every department with their own province and district for easy displaying, I had problems with it when I want to display in the blade, like when I display a department then I can only display only district or province, cant display both of them.
is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

To access to this properties. You should do a loop with for-each, but before you should send this data to blade or send blade property that you need. in your blade make this:

```
foreach($departaments as $departament){
     <p>{{ $departament->provinces->name }}</p>
}
```

for example

Answer (score 0):

From I understand from your question and also referring to the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships), your database table should be like this:

```
provinces
    id
    name

districts
    id
    name
    province_id

departments
    id
    name
    district_id
```

My suggestion is to not use the [pivot-based](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#retrieving-intermediate-table-columns) or [has many through](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through), considering on having a better way on displaying your data in **blade**, use [one to many](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) pattern should be more suitable.

For Department:

```php
class Department extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the district for the department.
     */
    public function district()
    {
        return $this->belongTo(District::class);
    }
}
```

For District:

```php
class District extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the departments for the district.
     */
    public function departments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Department::class);
    }

    /**
     * Get the provinces for the district.
     */
    public function provinces()
    {
        return $this->belongTo(Province::class);
    }
}
```

For Province:

```php
class Province extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the districts for the provinces.
     */
    public function districts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(District::class);
    }
}
```

The pattern I suggested here cannot access some patterns such as accessing all provinces with same departments, but can easily define in your controller or your model, but it should be more logical when trying to access them through **blade**, such as:

```html
<div>
    @foreach($departments as $department)
        <p>Department Name: {{ $department->name }}</P>
        <p>Department Province: {{ $department->province->name }}</P>
        <p>Department District: {{ $department->province->district->name }}</P>
    @endforeach
</div
```

If you are trying to access provinces' department, `$province->departments` will return an array of departments which is under the same provinces, and you can use the same way to access the data through blade as well.

So DPD table is not necessary at this point, hope this help you.